# Open a site directly in FileZilla using the command line

Tags: command-line, filezilla

I'm trying to open a site I created in [FileZilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla) using the command line. This is what have in my *.bat* file:

```
@echo off
filezilla.exe -c "0/mysitename"
pause
```

I'm getting the following error. How can I fix it?

> 'filezilla' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for an executable to be executed by name, the `filezilla.exe` file needs to be included on the `path`. This can be accomplished by

```
set path=%path%;the\directory\where\filezilla\resides
```

OR, you can use

```
the\directory\where\filezilla\resides\filezilla.exe -c "0/mysitename"
```